# How to show single list item without columns name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a sharepoint list contain one column and one text row.
I want to display the text row with out column name , only text.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a script editor web part in your page and add the below script:

```
<style>
.ms-viewheadertr {
   display:none;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of JQuery and HTML. you can create a JavaScript that fetches the data from the SharePoint list (using Rest Api) and build the HTML.
There was a StackOverflow [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244843/retrieving-list-items-from-sharepoint-online-to-html/244919) that how to fetch and show the record. Then use the script editor web part and configure your JavaScript file.